# C# DateTime for Twitter API created_at field

Tags: c#, .net-core, twitter

The v1 Twitter API returns `created_at` dates in the following format:

```
Mon Dec 28 11:32:24 +0000 2020
```

How can I parse this to a C# DateTime? I'm thinking I need to use the [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) method but I'm unsure what the format string should be and how I go about figuring it out

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to parse a `DateTime` like this with `ParseExact` the format string should look like the following:

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Dec 28 11:32:24 +0000 2020", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", null);
```

**ddd** - Abbreviated name of the Day

**MMM** - Abbreviated name of the Month

**dd** -  Day of the month as number 01-31

**h** - hour as 12 hour clock

**H** - 24 hour clock

**HH** - 24 hour clock with leading zero

**mm** - minutes

**ss** - seconds

**zzz** - With DateTime values represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours and minutes.

**yyyy** - year

For reference, this has a comprehensive list of datetime formating: [DateTime Formatting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: I think your answer should read `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` not `ddd MMM dd H:mm:ss zzz yyyy` (thanks for your help)

Comment: @VinylWarmth I updated the answer. You're welcome. Have a good day.